# Display\Capture InnerException Message

Tags: vb.net

I was using the following to provide more information on a common exception that can occour in a piece of my code, the only problem is this errors if an exception is generated that has no InnerException message.

```
Catch ex As Exception
     'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'If there is no InnerException.
     MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message)
End Try
```

Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a recursive function to keep grabbing the inner exceptions as long as they exist, that way you will get the full details if you have a single exception or 3 exceptions layered within each other.

```
Public Function ReadException(ByVal ex As Exception) As String
  Dim msg As String = ex.Message
  If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & "---------" & vbCrLf & ReadException(ex.InnerException)
  End If
  Return msg
End Function
```

and in your catch:

```
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ReadException(ex))
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

Just surround it by an If not nothing, but if you're doing it a lot, write a quick helper function like:

```
Private Function GetErrorText(ByVal ex As Exception) As String
    Dim err As String = ex.Message
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        err &= " - More details: " & ex.InnerException.Message
    End If
    Return err
End Function
```

Then you can just do `MessageBox.Show(GetErrorText(ex))`.